# Android - I modified vold.fstab and lost access to my SD card

Tags: external-sd

I have samsung galaxy ace GT-S5830, it has very low internal memory (181 MB).
I have an external micro SD card of 16 GB, but still couldn't install many apps due to insufficient internal memory.
I read in internet that if i modify vold.fstab and replace the word sdcard with sdcard2 in it, then my external sd card 
will act as internal memory.

So I rooted my phone and got superuser app (which can allow root access to various user apps)
But I haven't installed clockworkmod recovery or any other custom ROM yet.

I installed ES File explorer on SD card and allowed root access to it via superuser app.
I then went to `/system/etc/` from ES file explorer , edited vold.fstab and replaced the word sdcard with sdcard2 
Now i restarted my phone and the external SD is no more accessible. My "ES File Explorer" is also no more there for me to able 
to undo the change that i did.
I tried intalling ES file explorer again from my data connection, but the installation fails (and phone reboots immediately).
I am not able to install any new apps.

I am unable to access my external SD card, so I can't put anything there via PC or via recovery.

I tried pressing the power button + home button to go into system recovery mode. I see only these options

Androd system recovery <3e>

- reboot system now
- apply sdcard:update.zip
- wipe data/factory reset
- wipe cache partition

When i try to select the second option, it says installation aborted as the SD card is no more accessible

I tried to select 3rd and 4th options, but that didn't help either - I think factory reset will not reset vold.fstab :-(

I only have the default apps + superuser app now

I somehow need to find a way to get write permission to /system/etc or to `/system/etc/vold.fstab`

Luckily I found "Android Commander". Installing it on my windows PC and I am able to connect my android phone 
and I am able to access root folder. But I am not able to push a modified vold.fstab to `/system/etc because` 
Android Commander says "no Root Access" - It is seeing it as read only :-(

can someone let me know how i can edit this file again ? I have a original `vold.fstab` in my PC, but I am not able to push 
it to my phone via Android Commander as Android Commander is seeing it as Read Only.

Is there a way to give root access (aka read-write access) to Android Commander via superuser app on my android ?

Is there any other way to get write permission to `/system/etc/vold.fstab` so that i can modify it or replace it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Android Commander, but a simpler way (in my opinion) would be to use ADB. You may have already installed the Android SDK (if not, go [here](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22.0.1-windows.exe)). I assume that you don't have modified your System Path.

1. Move your `vold.fstab` to `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`
2. Go to the `android-sdk` folder, shift+right click on `platform-tools` and choose "Open command prompt here"
3. If your device is 4.0 or above, type `adb root`
4. `adb remount` (this will make `/system` writable)
5. `adb push vold.fstab /system`
6. `adb reboot`

This should do the trick.

Comment: my device is having froyo 2.2.1
and phone model is Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830

Comment: I'd remove windows specific instructions as they're not related to the question.